# How to get an image file name and send it to the feature extraction process in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, flask

I have an image retrieval program in python, I want to make a web-based program using flask. But, I don't understand how to get input images from flask. So I can process the input image in my image retrieval program then show the result in my flask page.

here my flask code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, Request, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'res/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 10 * 1024 * 1024

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port= 81)
```

and this is part of my image retrieval program, I need the input image from flask to fill `'inputImage.jpg'` on my `queryPath`:

```
from PIL import Image

# Define path of testing data and indexing file
queryPath = root_path + 'inputImage.jpg'
index_file = root_path + 'mtcd.csv'

# define the bins for quantization
colorBins = 64
R_Bins = 4
G_Bins = 4
B_Bins = 4
edgeBins = 18

query = cv2.imread(queryPath)

# Color Quantization
colorQuant = combineColorQuantization(query, B_Bins, G_Bins, R_Bins)

# Edge Quantization
edgeQuant = edgeQuantization(query, edgeBins)

# Texton Search
features = textonSearch(colorQuant, colorBins, edgeQuant, edgeBins)

# GLCM
glcm, en = GLCM(query)

features.extend(glcm[0])
features.extend(glcm[1])
features.extend(glcm[2])
features.extend(en)

# perform the search
searcher = Searcher(index_file)
results = searcher.search(features)

# display the query
fig = figure(figsize=(5,5))
title('Query Image')
imshow(array(Image.open(queryPath)))
axis('off')

# loop over the results
fig = figure(num=None, figsize=(20,5))
title('Result Image')
result = []
i = 1
for (score, resultID) in results:
    # load the result image and display it
    a = fig.add_subplot(2, 6, i)
    image = imread(root_path + 'batik/'+resultID)
    i += 1
    imshow(image)
    axis('off')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can def the image processing code as a seperate function like this

```
def process_file(path)
    # Define path of testing data and indexing file
    queryPath = path
    index_file = root_path + 'mtcd.csv'

    # define the bins for quantization
    colorBins = 64
    R_Bins = 4
    G_Bins = 4
    B_Bins = 4
    edgeBins = 18

    query = cv2.imread(queryPath)

    # Color Quantization
    colorQuant = combineColorQuantization(query, B_Bins, G_Bins, R_Bins)

    # Edge Quantization
    edgeQuant = edgeQuantization(query, edgeBins)

    # Texton Search
    features = textonSearch(colorQuant, colorBins, edgeQuant, edgeBins)

    # GLCM
    glcm, en = GLCM(query)

    features.extend(glcm[0])
    features.extend(glcm[1])
    features.extend(glcm[2])
    features.extend(en)

    # perform the search
    searcher = Searcher(index_file)
    results = searcher.search(features)

    # display the query
    fig = figure(figsize=(5,5))
    title('Query Image')
    imshow(array(Image.open(queryPath)))
    axis('off')

    # loop over the results
    fig = figure(num=None, figsize=(20,5))
    title('Result Image')
    result = []
    i = 1
    for (score, resultID) in results:
        # load the result image and display it
        a = fig.add_subplot(2, 6, i)
        image = imread(root_path + 'batik/'+resultID)
        i += 1
        imshow(image)
        axis('off')
    print(result)
```

call the process_file() method from flask route code block

```
  def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            process_file(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Comment: I need to trow the result of my image retrieval program to the flask. but I don't understand how to save the ` # load the result image and display it` into jpg with PIL,

Comment: Can u help me with that problem?

Comment: you can use image.show() to display the image using PIL (http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm)

Comment: I already use the image.show() but I need to save the resulting diagram into a jpg file and then access the jpg path in my flask page

Comment: Save the resulting diagram into the flask static folder and return the file path as URL to flask page.